# Remove Text Box Element From HTML Source

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net MVC3 . i have a button in my application and i want to hide to my textbox on button click. 
Problem is it hides on button click but when you do inspect element it shows the textbox element with property disabled .
and if user change the property i will be enabled again.

I want to hide the complete element from HTML Source

Comment: jQuery `.remove()` on the element

Comment: but it would remove the element and i will not be able to show the element again.

Comment: re-add it from code... updating example below (or use hide and show instead of disabling it)

Comment: The problem is, you have not shown an example of your HTML, or your code, so this is mostly guesswork :) If you can provide an actual example, you will get better answers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie there is nothing about html. i just want to know the technique how to achieve it.

Comment: OK... I have provide 3 possible how-to's below, but if you need more detail you will need to supply more detail of your specific situation. Perhaps a better explanation of the overall aim?

Comment: ok i got it and pretty helpful . i marked your answer correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.remove()` on the element to remove it from the DOM completely:

### e.g

```
$('.mytextclass').remove();
```

To re-add it, use `append()`

e.g.

```
$('.mytextcontainerclass').append('<input type="text" class="mytextclass"/>')
```

You can hide and show elements in any number of ways. If you only care about the enabled state being "hacked", use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead.

Another option: You can detach the element and store it in a global variable, or elsewhere in the DOM, then put it back later.

Comment: any example of another option would be very helpful ?

Comment: If you can show any HTML for your example, perhaps in a JSFiddle, then I will be happy to provide a specific example. Otherwise I will be making it up to suit myself, rather than to suit you :)